# GLX/GLEW order of initialization catch-22: GLXEW_ARB_create_context, glXCreateContextAttribsARB, glXCreateContext

Tags: opengl, x11, glew, glx

Currently I'm working on an application that uses GLEW and GLX (on X11).

The logic works as follows...

```
glewInit();  /* <- needed so 'GLXEW_ARB_create_context' is set! */
if (GLXEW_ARB_create_context) {
    /* opengl >= 3.0*/
    .. get fb_config ..
    context = glXCreateContextAttribsARB(...);
}
else {
    /* legacy context */
    context = glXCreateContext(...);
}
```

The problem I'm running into, is `GLXEW_ARB_create_context` is initialized by glew, but initializing glew calls `glGetString`, which crashes if its called before (`glXCreateContextAttribsARB` / `glXCreateContext`).

Note that this only happens with Mesa's software rasterizer, (libGL.so compiled with swrast). So its possibly a problem with Mesa too.

Answer (score 2):

Correction, this works on Mesa-SWRast and NVidia's propriatry OpenGL drivers, but segfaults with Intel's OpenGL.
*Though its possible this is a bug in the Intel drivers. Need to check how other projects handle this.*

The cause in this case is the case of intel is `glXGetCurrentDisplay()` returns NULL before glx is initialized (another catch-22).

So for now, as far as I can tell, its best do avoid `glew` before `glx` context is created, and instead use glx directly, eg:

```
    if (glXQueryExtension(m_display, NULL, NULL)) {
        const char *glx_ext = glXGetClientString(display, GLX_EXTENSIONS);
        if (... check_string_for_extension(glx_ext, "GLX_SOME_EXTENSION")) {
            printf("We have the extension!\n");
        }
    }
```

---

Old answer...

> Found the solution (seems obvious in retrospect!)
>
> - First call `glxewInit()`
> - check `GLXEW_ARB_create_context`
> - create the context with `glXCreateContextAttribsARB` or `glXCreateContext`.
> - call `glewInit()`